# Title: Multipart identifier s.Company_id could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I am getting the following error while executing the query .
Please help

Multipart identifier s.Company_id could not be bound

```
INSERT INTO Company_Item_Company_List 
(
    Company_id, 
    Company_item_id,
    client_id, 
    last_modified_timestamp, 
    last_modified_user_id 
)
SELECT 
    dcsl.distribution_center_id, 
    sisl.Company_item_id,
    @current_client_id:int, 
    getdate(), 
    @current_user_id:int
FROM Company_Item_Company_List AS sisl WITH (NOLOCK)
    JOIN Distribution_Center_Company_List AS dcsl WITH (NOLOCK) ON 
        dcsl.Company_id = sisl.Company_id
    JOIN Company AS s WITH (NOLOCK) ON 
        s.Company_id = sisl.Company_id AND s.distribution_center_flag = 'n' AND s.cdm_owner_id = s.client_id
    JOIN Company_Item_Base AS sib WITH (NOLOCK) ON 
        sib.Company_item_id = sisl.Company_item_id
WHERE sisl.Company_item_id = @Company_item_id:int
  AND s.Company_id = @Company_id:int
  AND sib.exception_status_code = 'n'
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM Company_Item_Company_List AS sisl2 WITH (NOLOCK)
                  WHERE sisl2.Company_item_id = sisl.Company_item_id
                    AND sisl2.Company_id = dcsl.distribution_center_id)
 AND EXISTS ( SELECT 1
              FROM   Company_packaged_item spi
              WHERE  spi.Company_id = @Company_id:int
              AND    spi.Company_item_id = sisl.Company_item_id
              AND    spi.cdm_owner_id = @current_client_id:int )
```

Comment: Could you reformat code please

Comment: It's very difficult to debug code visually. In order to encourage more response to your question you should consider posting suitable schema definitions and test data.

Comment: As John Sansom said - can you post/add to your question, the relevant table definitions? That way we can see things more easily.

Comment: Nice tidy layout. Should we credit SmartestVEGA or John Sansom with that?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure this variable syntax is correct `@current_client_id:int` I've never seen `@var:type` used before and my SQL Server doesn't seem to like it.

Comment: I've used SQL Server for almost ten years and have never seen this way of referencing a variable either and my SQL Server doesn't like it either.

Answer (score 0):

Does the table `Company` have the field named `Company_ID`?
I guess thats where it should begin.  If the field exists, have you spelt it correctly?